# How do I return range from normal distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Let's say I have 2 array of numbers as follows:

```
4.2 6.2 10.7 8.8 3.8 4.1
```

and

```
4.5 7.7 14.6 8.7 4.8 4.6
```

Also I generated standart deviation for first array:

```
0.010164 0.012286 0.013412 0.016488 0.00661 0.007426
```

Now for example on first element of array:

```
mean, sigma = 4.2, 0.010164
```

What I'm trying to do is to know whether each element of second array is in the range between std of each element of first array. In other words:

Whether 4.5 is within the range of `np.random.normal(mean, sigma)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So you will use the first array to generate the normal distribution i.e use the `avg<first array> -> \mu` and `std<first array> -> \sigma`? Then you want to what again?

Comment: I don't get it... Can you add a formula or something, explaining what you're trying to achieve? What is the std you want to compare against?

Comment: You want to fit a normal distribution to your data (e.g. array 1) and then check whether or not the values or array 2 are within the range of your standard deviation? You can fit the data with `from scipy.stats import norm` and `mean, std = norm.fit(array)`. From there it is only maths. Please correct me if I got that wrong.

Comment: @offeltoffel Tried to explain better. Please read the updated version

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It seems what I was looking for is [cumulative distribution function](http://www.dyinglovegrape.com/data_analysis/part1/1da2.php) which scipy has library for it.

```
import scipy.stats as ss

def f(x):
  return ss.norm.cdf(x, loc = 4.2, scale=0.010164 )

print f(4.5)
```

will return probability of 4.5 is in the normal distribution of 4.2 with a given standard deviation.